# Play php mp3 generated file without saving it or downloading

Tags: php, html

So i am generating mp3 file and it's working fine because when i download it i can play it just fine, but now what i want to do is output that file to my browser and play it in my browser, so what i have tried is:

```
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Content-Type: audio/mepeg');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"validate.mp3\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-length: $size");
```

**AND**

```
<embed autoplay="true" height="0" width="0" src="actions/play_file"  />
```

Well ofcourse id doesn't work, it just forces to download that file because i have used

`"Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"validate.mp3\"")`

And im so sure if im using right html tag for this?
But if i am, all i need is just right headers to make this work.

Comment: There's an HTML5 `audio` tag, isn't there?

Comment: Keep in mind that it is up to the browser to respect that header.  Some users (like myself) override the default functionality of our browser's to always download content of type audio/video.  If you have some kind of player (such as flash) you can better guarantee the file will play as intended.

Comment: @kurtzbot and what if i would save that mp3 file and then try to play from the server, would it always work?

Comment: @Linas I don't quite understand your question.  You can't choose to play audio files for the user after they have downloaded them.  The best you can do is use a player embedded in the browser that will automatically download the audio file from your server and play it.

Comment: @kurtzbot nevermind i found solution by myself, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to feed up the file:

```
header("Content-type: audio/mpeg");
header("Content-length: " . filesize($file));
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
readfile($file);
```

Or in chunks

```
$total     = filesize($filepath);
$blocksize = (2 << 20); //2M chunks
$sent      = 0;
$handle    = fopen($filepath, "r");

// Push headers that tell what kind of file is coming down the pike
header('Content-type: '.$content_type);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
header('Content-length: '.$filesize * 1024);

// Now we need to loop through the file and echo out chunks of file data
// Dumping the whole file fails at > 30M!
while($sent < $total){
    echo fread($handle, $blocksize);
    $sent += $blocksize;
}

exit(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

The important thing for you to do is specify the `Content-Type` header.  What the browser (or other user-agent) does with it is up to them, not to you.  The content type you are using now is incorrect.  Use `audio/mpeg`.

The only way to get it to always play is to include a player on a web page.  For that, you can use HTML5 audio tags, Flash, embed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

... and yet... Another more simpler approach ... I have tested this approach since the moment a Polish company by the name of Ivona, was purchased by Amazon on Jan. 24, 2013, so it is proven to work out of the box, after setting your AWS Polly credentials.

```
    header('Accept-Ranges: none');
    header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');

    echo $audio;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).