# Servlet that gets file from a url and sends it to users

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

So I'm relatively new to Javax Servlet and I"m supposed to modify some code at work. As requested by the company, I can't post my code up here. So basically I have a server set up on a cloud service and I deployed my app on that server. When I run my app, the users can type in :8080/appname/resources/filename. In the code, the filename will take me to the correct url of the file located on a CDN network. How can I play it back to the user through the servlet? Because it doesn't directly reside on my server but it's being directed somewhere else. I'll try to write a simple example to explain what I mean

```
procesRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse reponse){
  String requestFile = request.getPathInfo();
  File file = new File(basePath,URLDecoder.decode(requestedFile, "UTF-8"));
  RandomAccessFile input = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
  OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();

  playBack(input, output);
}

playBack(RandomAccessFile input, OutputStream output){
  byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
  int read;
  while ((read = input.read(buffer))>0)
  {
    output.write(buffer, 0, read);
  }
}
```

So in the above example, the file will reside on the server itself. And the basePath refers to the folder on the server where all the files are stored. So it can just playback the file. However, I want to modify it so that instead of getting a file on the server, it will get a file from a url and play it back. Right now I just have the URL hardcode in for testing purpose.

Comment: Please write a simplified example in case you cannot post the original code...

Answer (score 0):

Make a request to that server and just give back the response you get from that server.
Provided you have a webapp running at that server which accepts your requests, locate the file and give back the response to you.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details to go on, the conceptual solution is to open an input stream (file/data?) and read the contents while writing the same bytes read to the Servlet's output stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `URLConnection` for serves the real file. The following may inspire and help a little. You need to know what to replace on the request path (in the method `convertToRemoteUrl`).

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/resources/*" })
public class ResourceServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public static void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) 
            throws IOException {
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        for (int length; (length = in.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        in.close();
    }

    public static URL convertToRemoteUrl(final HttpServletRequest request) 
            throws MalformedURLException {
        URL url = request.getRequestURL();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(256);
        sb.append("http://realdomain.com");
        sb.append(url.getPath().replace(
                request.getContextPath(), "/realappname"));
        return new URL(sb.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        final URL url = convertToRemoteUrl(request);
        final URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        response.setContentType(connection.getContentType());
        copy(connection.getInputStream(), response.getOutputStream());
    }
}
```

e.g. The request URL can be converted from:

```
http://domain.com:8080/appname/resources/example.txt
```

to

```
http://realdomain.com:8080/realappname/resources/example.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems like something I can actually use. I already wrote a func similar to covertToRemoteURL, the problem I had was how to read it back to the buffer. Haha, I guess it wasn't as complicated as I thought. Beginner Alert!!!

Comment: hmmm, it seems like it's running fine but it's not reading the data back though. It's supposed to be an .mkv file.

Comment: Do you want read a file local to the application server or a remote file exposed by another application server?

Comment: it's a remote file on rackspace. And I have it's enabled as CDN content. So if I put the link of that file directly into the browser, it would start playing. I just want to call that from my servlet. So I have the URL completely replaced by the URL of the video file.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625844/play-php-mp3-generated-file-without-saving-it-or-downloading